# How to get the current connection string inside an Entity Framework migration?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there any migration property or singleton class the returns the current connection string inside a Entity Framework 5/6 migration? I need this inside of the migration "Up" method, I know it may sounds strange but I need this to perform some specific automation...

Comment: Is it possible to be a bit more specific? Maybe there are other ways to achieve what you want. As said in the answers: you can't do anything in the `Up` method that requires a connection. If you only need the connection _string_ you could use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`.

Answer (score 3):

The `Up` method is not connected. it only generates operations that will be executed later by the `DbMigrator`. If you want to do anything with a connection during a migration your only chance is the `Seed` method.

Answer (score 3):

Well it does sound a bit 'unortodox' :), but...

I'd suggest to use the `Seed` method of your `Configuration`

```
var connection = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

For migration Up/Down you could do something like this...

This works when you have a 'running' DbContext.

```
using (var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    var connection = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
}
```

(I didn't try that - as it should run)

---

#### EDIT: How To Get a Connections Cache w/o DbContext (Entity Framework):

---

*I think I understand now what you're trying to do (based on comments).*

You can get `all connections` using `Reflection` and from an `internal static dictionary`

```
IEnumerable<string> EnumerateConnections()
{
    var lazyInternalContextType = typeof(DbContext).Assembly
        .GetType("System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext");
    var propertyDbs = lazyInternalContextType.GetField(
        "InitializedDatabases", 
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
    var lazyContext = propertyDbs.GetValue(null);
    foreach (var pair in (IEnumerable)lazyContext)
    {
        var key = pair.GetType().GetProperty("Key")?.GetValue(pair, null);
        var tuple = (Tuple<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel, string>)key;
        yield return tuple.Item2; // need to replace "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;" with "" in EF6.
    }
}

var connectionName = EnumerateConnections().Distinct().SingleOrDefault();
```

You can put that into Up/Down - and you should get one 'distinct' connection that was used.

This works providing you do not mix different connections. In that case you'd need to tweak this based on your scenario.

(should work for both EF5 and EF6, classes are the same - I just confirmed it fast for EF5):

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to run it inside the Up method and if I just create an instance of my DbContext it wont respect the connection string in the Update-Database -ConnectionString command.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It pretty much solved my issue. Since this is back to 2013 and I am running EF6 now, the item2 returns "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;Data Source=localhost..." which includes the provider. So `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;` needs to be manually replaced with empty string.